# Storing 300 records iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am reading a JSON feed with about 300 array records. Each record is an object with about 8 entries. Is that a lot to store locally in a dictionary upon start up?

If so, should I just read data from the feed online each time data is requested?

Comment: no it's not , how much is you feed length and size ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach with the less amount of code is to store the dictionary in a plist and query the data yourself. The iPhone can handle 300 objects in memory without delays so I wouldn't bother with anything else unless I had to. When to refresh the feed depends on your application logic.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"feed" ofType:@"plist"];
[dict writeToFile:path atomically:YES]; // write
[dict dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path]; // read
[dict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key,id obj,BOOL *stop){ //iterate
    NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", key, obj]);
}];
```

For a little more performance use a binary plist. If you have to make complex queries then use `NSPredicate` or Core Data.

Comment: This is not what NSUserDefaults is for, it is for preferences and settings. Do not use it to store data pertinent to the app, either keep a plist in the documents directory or use coredata. This is a bad approach.

Comment: As per docs... "The defaults system allows an application to customize its behavior to match a user’s preferences. For example, you can allow users to determine what units of measurement your application displays or how often documents are automatically saved. Applications record such preferences by assigning values to a set of parameters in a user’s defaults database. The parameters are referred to as defaults since they’re commonly used to determine an application’s default state at startup or the way it acts by default."

Comment: +1 I edited the answer. There is really no reason to use `NSUserDefaults` instead a plist. It wastes a millisecond looking up `NSArgumentDomain`, goes against convention, and it's designed for something else so there is some extra information you don't need to learn.

Answer (score 3):

If it doesn't change often, you could cache it into a Core Data store, and update individual records that are different, deleted or newly added, instead of recreating the store on start-up.

Even if it does change often, another advantage of using CD is that you can quickly query your Core Data store for specific records, instead of (possibly) iterating through each record.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you should  just read data from the feed online each time data is requested. Although 300 array records is not too much large data. But in case of live feeds you should always read the data each time data is requested.

Comment: This does not make sense, caching is an integral part of client / server architectures, check for new data but why download ALL the original data every time? You are using unnecessary bandwidth and time, not a good approach.